# Is it safe to use url shortening while sharing secure links?

Tags: security, url-shortener

I want to share one time access links with guids. We would like no one to guess the urls to these one time links. Can I use url shortening for this? Can I maintain the same level of security I get with plain url with guid?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sharing secret links is most of the time not very secure, especially if transmitted via insecure channels. If you sent the link to an URL shortening service you still need to keep the result secret and you add additional risks: the transfer to the service, the transfer from the serive, to storage at the service (you have to trust them) and the shorting servie might use guessable short ids. So all in all the situation gets much more risky. But you already have a high risk with your secret links, so it might not matter much :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use a uuid, it is not going to be easy to guess. I can get around with the leakage by using my own shortening service. However, the moment you make it short, it becomes easy to guess like you've said. I am thinking of keeping these short urls short lived to mitigate the risk.

Comment: Yes if the shortener uses a method like counting upwards from 1 then the links are very easy enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see is that the URL shortening service will redirect the user to the full url, which will appear in the user's browser location bar or history.  Generating a one time use URL with an expiry would be more useful.